# Using Excel ComboBox to pull information from one file to another

Tags: vba, combobox, excel-2010, copy-paste

I am trying to copy information from an excel database file to an excel display file. I have figured out how to copy that information in and I have different macros depending on the different information I am looking at. These seem to be working by themselves.

However I also want to include a dropdown field that will then allow the user to select which set of data they would like to see (basically which customer). My code is below, I am new to the site so if any formatting is incorrect please let me know so I can improve it :)

```
    Private Sub ComboBox1_Click()

    Select Case ComboBox1.Value
      Case "Acme"
        'Acme Macro
        ' Pulls Acme Customer Information from Database for each Segment
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Windows("Product_List_Template.xlsx").Activate
        Sheets("Segment1").Range("C1:C278").Copy
        Windows("Tool V0A.xlsm").Activate
        Sheets("Segment1").Range("J1:J278").Paste
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Windows("Product_List_Template.xlsx").Activate
        Sheets("Segment2").Range("C1:C278").Copy
        Windows("Tool V0A.xlsm").Activate
        Sheets("Segment2").Range("J1:J278").Paste
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Sheets("Dashboard").Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Calculate
      Case "Ball"
        ' Ball Macro
        ' Pulls Ball Customer Information from Database for each Segment
        Windows("Product_List_Template.xlsx").Activate
        Sheets("Segment1").Select
        Range("D1:D278").Select
        Selection.Copy
        Windows("Tool V0A.xlsm").Activate
        Sheets("Segment1").Select
        Range("J1:J278").Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        Windows("Product_List_Template.xlsx").Activate
        Sheets("Segment2").Select
        Range("D1:D278").Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Selection.Copy
        Windows("Tool V0A.xlsm").Activate
        Sheets("Segment2").Select
        Range("J1:J278").Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        Sheets("Dashboard").Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Calculate
      Case Else
        Exit Sub
    End Select
    End Sub
```

So the code is selecting the correct Case and then when it starts into the designated macro, I am having a "Run-time error '1004': Select method of Range class failed" popping up. When I go to debug the code it has "Range("D1:D278").Select" highlighted as when it failed. I have tried copying columns, I have tried copying smaller ranges, and nothing is working. All the cells in the range have information in them but for some reason it is just not working. I really appreciate anyone's help!

Comment: Check Tim Williams' answer below. Using, or relying on the `Selection` and `Activate` methods is error-prone, as you're discovering, unless you fully qualify each reference. But 99% of the time, you can avoid these methods and just work with the objects directly. Select/Activate is mostly superfluous.  Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Click()

    Dim wbPlt As Workbook, wbTool As Workbook, sourceRange As String

    Set wbPlt = Workbooks("Product_List_Template.xlsx")
    Set wbTool = ThisWorkbook 'Workbooks("Tool V0A.xlsm")

    Select Case ComboBox1.Value
      Case "Acme": sourceRange = "C1:C278"
      Case "Ball": sourceRange = "D1:D278"
      Case Else: sourceRange = ""
    End Select

    'copy if have source range
    If sourceRange <> "" Then

        wbPlt.Sheets("Segment1").Range(sourceRange).Copy _
                   wbTool.Sheets("Segment1").Range("J1")

        wbPlt.Sheets("Segment2").Range(sourceRange).Copy _
                   wbTool.Sheets("Segment2").Range("J1")

        wbTool.Sheets("Dashboard").Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Calculate

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Got the error on Line 5 when it was trying to find the workbook, I had it open and its in the same folder, but apparently it opened in a separate excel environment. The problem I am encountering now is it is not doing the calculate function at the end of the program. Thanks again!

Comment: When you say it's "not doing" the calculate what exactly is happening - nothing, or you get an error?

Comment: It is not calculating and updating. The data is pulled, but the formulas are not updated based on the new data pulled in.

Comment: Try `CalculateFull` or `CalculateFullRebuild`

Comment: Hi Tim, if I use either of those I am getting a "Sub or Function not Defined."

Comment: Try prefixing with `Application.`

Comment: Awesome that works perfectly! Thank you very much for all of your help with this!